# Android 5 camera2 interface. Some of White Balance values doesn't have effect

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

Strange behavior on my Nexus 5 device with Android 5.0.1 official firmware.

According to documentation, camera2 interface supports 9 values of WB.
Nexus 5 supports all of them (android.control.awbAvailableModes returns all possible WBs)

Almost all of them works fine and white balance of preview is changed. But 3 of them has no effect: WARM_FLUORESCENT, TWILIGHT and SHADE

Here is a code how I set white balance:

```
if (mode != CameraParameters.WB_MODE_AUTO)
            HALv3.previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        else
            HALv3.previewRequestBuilder
                    .set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_USE_SCENE_MODE);

        HALv3.previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, mode);
        try
        {
            CameraController.iCaptureID = HALv3.getInstance().mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(
                    HALv3.previewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see, there's nothing special, all things doing according documentation.

Comment: Is there anything else discovered on this finding?  My Nexus 5 has the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

it's same when you use camera API.

Comment: Wow! You're right! Old camera api has the same behaviour. Moreover, I've tested FV5 camera application and they too has that problem. So, it's mean that Nexus 5 firmware has a bug?

Comment: I don't think so. It's same when use camera API on my phone.Maybe the effect is not obvious

Comment: @yydcdut It's not about a subtle change either.  Both daylight and fluorescent are very different white balances.  If you try and change to those values from either one you don't notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It does look as though there is a bug with the firmware on the Nexus 5.  As a developer with various different devices at the desk, the Nexus 5 behaves different than the rest of them with the white balance change.

Samsung S4, reports valid white point and demonstrates those changes.
Samsung S5, good.
Moto X, good.
HTC One M7, good.
Xiaomi Mi4, good.

I will go under the assumption that the whiteBalancesAvailable() call is returning the entire list, when it should only be returning the ones you specified with positive effects.

I wanted to report this for anyone else who runs across this as an issue.

**edit:** They are aware of this and will be making note of this in a future update release.